# Wave and relativity

Tags: special-relativity, classical-mechanics, energy, waves, mass-energy

From Wikipedia, "In physics, a wave is a disturbance that transfers energy through matter or space, with little or no associated mass transport." But Einstein said that energy equals mass so if a wave transfers energy therefore it transfer mass?

Comment: Related Q & A here:  [Don't all waves transport mass?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/251473/140996)

Answer (score 1):

> But Einstein said that energy equals mass

In fact, 'Einstein said' that the total energy of a particle of invariant mass $m$ is (see [Energy-momentum relation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Energy%E2%80%93momentum_relation))

$$E = \sqrt{(pc)^2 + (mc^2)^2}$$

and so, for $mc^2 \ll pc$,

$$E \approx pc$$

which is exact for massless particles.  Thus, e.g, there can be electromagnetic waves that transport energy and momentum without transporting mass.

Answer (score 0):

You're very nearly correct: mass and energy are equivalent through $E=mc^2$ (assuming $p$ is insignificant), yet they are not the same, light does not have mass yet it does have energy and the same is true for waves

Answer (score 0):

A better formulation would be to replace *mass* with *matter*:

> In physics, a wave is a disturbance that transfers energy through matter or space, with little or no associated transport of matter.

Indeed, energy is heavy and behaves in that way as mass. The equation $E = mc^2$ really says that energy and mass are equivalent. But many physicists want to reserve the notation of *mass* for what is sometimes called *rest mass*. You can see this in the other answers, like "light does not have mass" (in [answer by Cursed](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/434933/149169)).